# Generate new rows in pandas by adding values based on previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a df that looks like this:

```
+------+----+----+
| Name | P1 | P2 |
+------+----+----+
| A    |  1 |  1 |
| B    |  1 |  2 |
| C    | -5 |  3 |
+------+----+----+
```

and I want to generate new rows where I've added +2 to P1 and +1 to P2 so it'll look like this

```
+------+----+----+
| Name | P1 | P2 |
+------+----+----+
| A    |  1 |  1 |
| B    |  1 |  2 |
| C    | -5 |  3 |
| NA   |  3 |  2 |
| NA   |  3 |  3 |
| NA   | -3 |  4 |
+------+----+----+
```

As shown I don't really care about the Name col for the new data. (the Name col can be whatever, it can be a copy of where p1 and p2 got its data from or it can just be empty/nan/na that col isn't important to me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.add` with a list, then use `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[*'ABC'],
                   'P1':[1,1,-5],
                   'P2':[1,2,3]})
pd.concat([df, df[['P1','P2']].add([2,1])], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  Name  P1  P2
0    A   1   1
1    B   1   2
2    C  -5   3
3  NaN   3   2
4  NaN   3   3
5  NaN  -3   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

1. Just set the `Name` column as index and add [2,1] to each column respectively.
2. Concatenate over `axis=0` with original dataframe

```
new_df = df.set_index('Name')+[2,1]

pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=0)
```

```
  Name  P1  P2
0    A   1   1
1    B   1   2
2    C  -5   3
3  NaN   3   2
4  NaN   3   3
5  NaN  -3   4
```